# Specifying width and height for editfield makes a difficulty to see the text in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-editfield

I have used `EditField` with some specified width and height that works good but, when I'm entering the text in `EditField` I'm unable to see the text and some times when I'm clicking on that I'm getting `NullPointerException`. I'm not able to understand whether the text is entered or not. Also, I cannot see the cursor in my field. If there are any mistakes please give me suggestions.

My code is:

```
       private EditField edto;
       private int tosetWidth =400 ,tosetHeight = 50;
       public WelcomeScreen()
       {
           /* Border For EditFields */
           Border bdr = BorderFactory.createRoundedBorder(new XYEdges(4, 4, 4, 4),Border.STYLE_SOLID);

           edto = new EditField(){

           protected void layout(int width, int height)
           {        
               setExtent(tosetWidth, tosetHeight);

           }

       };

       edto.setBorder(bdr);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Text not showing because of this

```
protected void layout(int width, int height)
        {        
            setExtent(tosetWidth, tosetHeight);

        }
```

just remove and try your code is working

if you want to edit field with vertical scrolling and fixed size try following

```
/**
 * A class extending the MainScreen class, which provides default standard
 * behavior for BlackBerry GUI applications.
 */
public final class MyScreen extends MainScreen
{
    /**
     * Creates a new MyScreen object
     */
    public MyScreen()
    {        
        // Set the displayed title of the screen       
        setTitle("My Edit box Example");

        VerticalFieldManager vr=new VerticalFieldManager(VERTICAL_SCROLL|VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR)
        {
            protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
                super.sublayout(200,100);
                setExtent(200, 100);
            }
        };

        Border bdr = BorderFactory.createRoundedBorder(new XYEdges(4, 4, 4, 4),Border.STYLE_SOLID);
        EditField edto = new EditField(){
            public void paint(Graphics g) 
            {
                getManager().invalidate();
                super.paint(g);
            }
     };

     vr.setBorder(bdr);
     vr.add(edto);
     add(vr);
     }
}
```

you can get output as following

[image]